# main activity does not wait for sub activity to finish

Tags: java, android

I'm quite new to Java and Android, so be gentle :)
I trying to start ActivityForResult to enable bluetooth, but seems that main activity keeps running and executes getPaireddevices without wiaitng for ActivityForresult to finish. What is my mistake here?

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
    if (BtAdapter==null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Bluetooth adapter...",0 ).show();
        finish();
    } else {
        if (!BtAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    }
    GetPairedDevices();
}


    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "too bad..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `GetPairedDevices();` into your `onActivityResult()`

Somthing like

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "too bad..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
         GetPairedDevices();
    }
```

this way `onCreate()` can finish and that function will only run if you enable bluetooth, which I believe is what you want

If you want it to run if Bluetooth is enabled and not `null` in `onCreate()` then you may want to change your `onCreate()` to something like

```
       @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
    if (BtAdapter==null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Bluetooth adapter...",0 ).show();
        finish();
    } elseif (BtAdapter != null && !BtAdapter.isEnabled()){
          Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
          startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
      }
    else{
     GetPairedDevices();
    }

}
```

**Note:**

This was just a quick example of how you need to do it because `onCreate()` is going to finish executing the remaining code in the function. I haven't tested it or know all of your code but something like this should help.

Comment: yes, you probable right, but i have plans to write more code into onCreate activity, like open sockets and so on... I just have to be sure that subactivty is finished before continuing with other operations...

Comment: Then you should put them in `onActivityForResult()` or move them to the last `else` as in my example

Answer (score 0):

If you want your function GetPariedDevices to be called after your subactivity finishes you have to put that call inside your *onActivityResult* function, if not, it will get called because the onCreate function will continue executing the rest of the sentences.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: So I was living in a dream that main activity will wait for result before continuing... thanks for breaking that dream :)